# How to change the order of discord-py-slash commands

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to change the order of slash commands in discod-py-slash commands.
[This is my current order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtklS.png)

I want to change the position help command to the top, and 8ball to the 3rd place.

I tried changing the order of the commands in code, but it didn't work.
Thx in advance.

Comment: I am fairly sure slash commands just show up in alphabetical order and as far as I know, there isn't a way to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think now you can't change order of slash commands, they are arranged in alphabetical order, so if you wanna change something - just rename the command